# How to convert database table in C# into a multi level JSON

Tags: c#, json, database, loops

I have this IEnumerable collection coming from the database that looks similar to this:

```
SectionID SectionName SubSectionID SubSectionName TagID TagName
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         Section 1   null         null           1     Tag 1
2         Section 2   null         null           2     Tag 2
3         Section 3   1            SubSection 1   3     Tag 3
3         Section 3   2            SubSection 2   3     Tag 3
3         Section 3   3            SubSection 3   3     Tag 3
4         Section 4   null         null           2     Tag 2
5         Section 5   null         null           1     Tag 1
...
```

How can I conver this table into JSON that will look similar to this format:

```
[
   {
       "SectionID": 1,
       "SectionName": "Section 1",
       "TagID": 1,
       "TagName": "Tag 1"
   },
   {
       "SectionID": 2,
       "SectionName": "Section 2",
       "TagID": 2,
       "TagName": "Tag 2"
   },    
   {
       "SectionID": 3,
       "SectionName": "Section 3",
       "SubSection": 
             {
                "SubSectionID": 1,
                "SubSectionName": "SubSection 1"
             },
             {
                "SubSectionID": 2,
                "SubSectionName": "SubSection 2"
             },
             {
                "SubSectionID": 3,
                "SubSectionName": "SubSection 3"
             },
       "TagID": 3,
       "TagName": "Tag 3",
   },
    {
       "SectionID": 4,
       "SectionName": "Section 4",
       "TagID": 2,
       "TagName": "Tag 2"
   },
   {
       "SectionID": 5,
       "SectionName": "Section 5",
       "TagID": 1,
       "TagName": "Tag 1"
   }
...
```

So the sub section part is optional. I tried to use string builder with a loop and an inner loop to create my JSON but it pretty messy and complicated.

Is there an easy way to do this in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form your desired structure with linq and anonymous objects like this:

```
var result = yourEnumerable
    .GroupBy(s => new {s.SectionID, s.SectionName, s.TagID, s.TagName})
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Key.SectionID,
        x.Key.SectionName,
        x.Key.TagID,
        x.Key.TagName,
        SubSection = x.Count() == 1 ? null : x.Select(y => new
        {
            y.SubSectionID,
            y.SubSectionName
        }).ToArray()
    });
```

Then you can serialize it with `JsonConvert`:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, settings);
```

See a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jah8pz)

Comment: That was great, thanks for this. I added this code before sending it to my web project and that fixed an error I had in my Angular project.   

object parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
return Ok(parsedJson);